# Get value of atomic counter (increment) with Rails and Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, atomic, sidekiq

I need to atomically increment a model counter and use its new value (processed by a Sidekiq job).

At the moment, I use

```
Group.increment_counter :tasks_count, @task.id
```

in my model which atomically increments the counter.

**But** I also need its new value to send a notification, if the counter has e.g. the value `50`. Any ideas? Locking the table/row or is there an easier way?

**Edit / SOLUTION**

Based on *mu is too short*'s answer and Rails's `update_counters` method , I implemented an instance method (tested with PostgreSQL).

```
def self.increment_counter_and_return_value(counter_name, id)
  quoted_column = connection.quote_column_name(counter_name)
  quoted_table = connection.quote_table_name(table_name)
  quoted_primary_key = connection.quote_column_name(primary_key)
  quoted_primary_key_value = connection.quote(id)

  sql = "UPDATE #{quoted_table} SET #{quoted_column} = COALESCE(#{quoted_column}, 0) + 1 WHERE #{quoted_table}.#{quoted_primary_key} = #{quoted_primary_key_value} RETURNING #{quoted_column}"
  connection.select_value(sql).to_i
end
```

Use it like:

```
Group.increment_counter_and_return_value(:tasks_count, @task.id)
```

It uses `RETURNING` to fetch the new value within the same query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Group.increment_counter` call sends SQL like this to the database:

```
update groups
set tasks_count = coalesce(tasks_counter, 0) + 1
where id = X
```

where `X` is `@task.id`. The SQL way to get the new `tasks_counter` value is to include a RETURNING clause:

```
update groups
set tasks_count = coalesce(tasks_counter, 0) + 1
where id = X
returning tasks_count
```

I don't know of any convenient Railsy way to get that SQL to the database though. The usual Rails approach would be to either do a bunch of locking and reload `@task` or skip the locking and hope for the best:

```
Group.increment_counter :tasks_count, @task.id
@task.reload
# and now look at @task.tasks_count to get the new value
```

You can use RETURNING like this though:

```
new_count = Group.connection.execute(%Q{
    update groups
    set tasks_count = coalesce(tasks_counter, 0) + 1
    where id = #{Group.connection.quote(@task.id)}
    returning tasks_count
}).first['tasks_count'].to_i
```

You'd probably want to hide that mess behind a method on `Group` so that you could say things like:

```
n = Group.increment_tasks_count_for(@task)
# or
n = @task.increment_tasks_count
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this. I updated my question with an instance method based on your answer.